# PDO MySQL check if database exists

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, schema

What would be the proper way of asking wether or not a `SCHEMA` exists in a MySQL Database?

I am programming in PDO and basically my script should be something like this:

```
if (databaseExists($db)) {
    // Do something
}
```

And for the function:

```
function databaseExists($db) {
     SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = $db;
     if so - return true;
     else - return false;
}
```

My question is actually, how to implement the `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = $db` statement. Do I have to use a `$conn` which doesn't have a database defined? And how would I return the results? Do I have to fetch the data, or is it just possible to make a count?

Comment: What has this got to do with PHP sessions?

Comment: You can establish the connection using INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the dbname.

Comment: @MartinBean I actually don't know why it had the title.. Probably a stackoverflow cookie from an earlier question I was writing.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Please write it as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Go ahead and accept the user's who has posted it below. I don't need the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create your connection directly to the info schema and run your query.

```
$pdo = new PDO(
               'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
               'username',
               'password'
);
```

From there, your function should work once build out.